# Where does this declaration come from: main _2a((argc,argv), int argc, char * argv[])

Tags: c, oracle-pro-c

I am migrating lots of Oracle Pro*C Code under HP-Unix to a Linux Environment.

In a program there is only such a main method defined:

```
main _2a((argc,argv), int argc, char * argv[])
{
...
}
```

I have never seen such a decalaration before - and haven't found anything with google.
Anyhow, it works and from what I see is used as a main function.

Can anybody tell something about this?

Edit:
Good hint - there is a macro definition:

```
 # define _2a(list,a1,a2)                 list a1;a2;
```

Still makes no clear view (for me..)

Comment: `_2a` is most likely a macro, defined in some header file.

Comment: Maybe `_2a` is a macro.

Comment: good hint - i can see a macro definition. I am updating the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We just have to expand the macro.  You can use `gcc -E` to invoke just the preprocessor; it will also expand all `#include` directives, so the output is going to be ugly.

But let's do it manually. The arguments to the macro are token sequences, not expressions.

The macro definition is:

```
# define _2a(list,a1,a2)                 list a1;a2;
```

and the invocation is:

```
main _2a((argc,argv), int argc, char * argv[])
{
...
}
```

The arguments are:

- `list` --> `(argc,argv)`
- `a1`   --> `int argc`
- `a2`   --> `char * argv[]`

Performing the replacements gives us:

```
main (argc,argv) int argc; char * argv[];
{
...
}
```

This would more commonly be written on multiple lines:

```
main(argc, argv)
int argc;
char *argv[];
{
    ...
}
```

This is an *old-style* function declaration. It's still legal in all versions of C (up to and including the 2011 standard), but it's been officially obsolescent since 1989. The disadvantage of this old form is that it didn't communicate parameter information to callers, so a compiler couldn't warn you if you called a function with the wrong number of types of arguments.

I'll bet there's an alternate definition of the `_a2` macro that expands to more modern definition that includes a prototype, something like:

```
#define _2a(list,a1,a2) (a1, a2)
```

With that macro definition, the definition of `main` instead expands to this:

```
main (int argc, char * argv[])
{
...
}
```

So the `_a2` macro (the "a" presumably stands for "argument") lets you write code that can expand *either* to an old-style function definition (for pre-ANSI compilers) or to a modern definition with a prototype.

A reasonable way to implement it would have been:

```
#ifdef __STDC__
#define _2a(list,a1,a2) (a1, a2) 
#else
#define _2a(list,a1,a2) list a1;a2;
#endif
```

But since you're very unlikely to find a C compiler that doesn't support prototypes (they've been a standard feature of the language for a quarter of a century now), it would make more sense just to remove the macro altogether and just use modern style function declarations and definitions.

Also, the definition of `main` is missing the return type of `int`. Prior to the 1999 C standard, it was legal to omit the return type, under the "implicit `int`" rule.  The 1999 standard dropped this rule and made an explicit return type mandatory. Most C compilers in their default mode still permit the return type to be omitted, perhaps with a warning, but there's no good reason to omit it.

Comment: This is a very well written answer which includes lots of information. I can only give +1 because I have no +2 - I am very sorry to not accept your great answer as "the answer" because I have already marked Kay's answer. it provided me with the information I needed and was slightly faster - also my own policy does not allow to switch a ticked answer - i am sorry for that. Anyhow I call on everybody to also upvote this answer.

Comment: @Stefan: On the rare occasions when I post questions, I usually wait a little while before accepting an answer. (I'm not saying this to suggest that my answer should have been the accepted one; that's entirely up to you. BTW, I upvoted the other answer.)

Comment: I wouldn't be offended if you changed your accepted answer. I usually wait a day or two, before accepting an answer, because it attracts more visitors and often the answers get more upvotes because of that, too. :)

Comment: Thank you for your nice responses - in this case I will stick the answer to Keith as his answer contains a well written and explained behaviour. thank you both.

Answer (score 8):

This macro is used to make [K&R C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%26R_C)-style function definition look more like "modern" C89 definitions.

Expanded the code reads:

```
main (argc,argv) int argc;char * argv[];
{
...
}
```

Or with a better indentation:

```
main(argc, argv)
    int argc;
    char *argv[];
{
    ...
}
```

Which is an ancient way to write:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Are you able to explain what the preprocessor is doing? I try to figure out what replacement is done before the compilation starts.

Comment: I put the plain macro expansion into my question. Does this answer your question?

Comment: I am just trying to help humanity with the powers I acquired from the years of CRT monitor radiation exposure. ;)

Comment: I'll just point out that it's not *quite* equivalent to `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`. The latter causes arguments to be implicitly converted (if they're of an implicitly convertible type) or diagnosed if they're not of the expected type; with a non-prototype definition/declaration, a call with bad arguments has undefined behavior. Also, omitting the return type and letting it default to `int` was legal up to and including C89/C90/C95, but was never a particularly good idea.